# What is meant by $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}^k$? Set notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just a simple question. Very stupid but I searched my textbook and the internet and can't find the answer. I don't understand what it means for a set to have a power of k.
Say you have a set S that is a subset of {0,1}^k. Does {0,1}^k refer to the set of all bit strings of at most length k? Or length exactly k?
I don't understand.

Comment: Yes; it is the Cartesian product of {$0,1$} with itself $k$ times, or, as you said, the set of all strings of $0$'s and $1$'s of length $k$.

Comment: Thank you! :) Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It denotes the set of all tuples of length $k$ consisting of elements of the set $\{0,1\}$. Because the elements of this particular set are $0$ and $1$, it is natural to identify this with the set of binary strings of length $k$.